# XPAGES will not save existing document while using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xpages

I have tried select2 plugin on XPAGES. It's working properly for new document but for existing document, it can't be saved. And I have found source of this problem is "XPAGES will not save existing document while using $.ajax" and XAgent

Here my simple sample (test.xsp) :`

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Employee"
        action="openDocument" computeWithForm="both">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xc:coreHeader theme="blue"></xc:coreHeader>
<xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:currentDocument.save();context.redirectToPage("grid.xsp");}]]>
    </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button id="button2" rendered="#{javascript:!currentDocument.isEditable()}" value="Edit">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
        <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="toggle" var="document1"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xp:label for="forteInputText" styleClass="control-label" value="Label"></xp:label>
<xp:div styleClass="controls" >         
    <xp:inputText id="txtNama" value="#{document1.Nama}"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:inputText id="txtAlamat" value="#{document1.Alamat}"></xp:inputText>
</xp:div>
<xp:scriptBlock rendered="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[// DECLARATION
        dojo.ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'example.xsp'
            }).done(function(data){
                x$('#{id:txtNama}').val(data);
            })  
    })]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
<xc:coreFooter></xc:coreFooter>
</xp:view>
```

and XAgent (example.xsp)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">
    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    try{
        var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
        var result = "ajax testing";
        writer.write(result);
        writer.endDocument();
    }  catch(e){
        _dump(e); 
    }
}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

When I open url "server/database.nsf/test.xsp" . TxtNama will get value : "ajax testing" from example.xsp and I save it.. that new document can be saved without any problem.

However when I open that saved document url = "server/database.nsf/test.xsp?documentId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX". and fill txtAlamat value and save it. Any changes in txtAlamat can't be saved.

But if I set xp:scriptBlock rendered="false" and try to fill txtAlamat value again, that changes of txtAlamat is saved.

It's very odd..

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do: I don't see your use of select2, I don't understand why you want to call your ajax function, and I don't see that example.xsp is trying to save anything. Here's a Select2 with XPages demo that might be useful: http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/select2.xsp

Comment: sorry to make you confused.. I try to use select2 plugin. but XPAGES can only save document for new document only. And I try to squeeze some code to find root cause of this problem. And I found, in my database, I can't save any changes for existing document while I use $.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- Check if you are actually allowed to edit the document and save the changes. Might be that you don't have enough access to update it.
- I tested your scenario: opened test.xsp, created a document, opened test.xsp?documentId=xxx, made a change to the field and successfully updated the document. Note that if you then open test.xsp?documentId=xxx again, the updated value is shown. But if you click the Edit button, the XPage is put in edit mode and the value of the input is changed back to 'ajax testing' because the ajax call kicks in again. You might want to change the code to only perform the ajax call for new documents. If you want to make sure your changes are saved, view the document using the Notes client.

Comment: thanks for your reply - I have manager access for this database's ACL - I have tried this scenario too.. but it still can be saved only for new document. For existing document, any changes can be saved if I set scriptBlock render off (disable $.ajax calling). And I still have no idea what cause this odd problem. Would you mind to send me your testing scenario nsf to my mail ? please send it to hedikasmanto@gmail.com so I can compare what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Try this: create a document using test.xsp, open that document using test.xsp?id=xxx, click Edit (the field will change back to 'ajax testing'), update the field and click Save. Now check the document in the database using the Notes client. You will see that it has changed. The problem with your code is that the Ajax call 'resets' the field every time you open a document.

Comment: that form have 2 field : Nama and Alamat. And I only set $.ajax for fill "Nama" with "ajax testing" from example.xsp. I set "Alamat" field as free text, and when I try to edit "Alamat" on existing document, it  didn't save. Also I add "print('save successfully') on postSave, and that script only fired when I save new document not for existing document.

Comment: Mark. I have tried to create new database.. and it works like you said.. so I think my current database have something error that I don't know where.. and I will find the root cause of this problem. But thanks for your help.. I really appreciate

Comment: finally.. I have found the "culprit" I had set xsp.persistence.viewstate=delta in application setting.. And when I try to remove it on my current database, it solve this problem..